# How to specify BatchSize for JPAQueryFactory to avoid round trips

Tags: spring, performance, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using JPAQuery to query the database and facing latency while retrieving it, I have also provided BatchSize but looks like it's not getting honored. The query is taking around 2seconds to query and retrieve, however, the actual execution time is on 19 milliseconds. Please advise.

```
JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
JPAQuery query = queryFactory.select(queryBase.getColumns()).distinct().from(entityPath);

joinConditionsList.forEach(addDynamicJoins(query));
query
    .where(queryBase.getFilters())
    .orderBy(queryBase.getOrderBy())
    .offset(queryBase.getOffset())
    .limit(50000);
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

List<Tuple> list = query.fetch();
```

I have provided the following in the application.yml.

```
jpa:
  show-sql: true
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: none
    batch_size: 234
  naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
  properties:
    hibernate:
      jdbc:
        lob:
          non_contextual_creation: true
        batch_size: 235
      temp:
        use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Comment: batch size isn't fetch size... Batch size is for inserts/updates that should be merged into a single INSERT/UPDATE statement. The fetch size is used for how many rows are retrieved in one go (on the SQL level!). Also creating all those objects takes time, so comparing query executing with executing, retrieval, mapping isn't really fair.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I agree that comparing those will not be apple to apple, but  19 milliseconds to 2000+ milliseconds is huge and I am doubting the latency due to multiple roundtrips.